# SFDX Pull fails because of AppMenu/AppSwitcher

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, winter19

I created a scratch org with the new Winter release.
After pushing my code without trouble, and updated it, I wanted to pull it to local files using :

```
sfdx force:source:pull --forceoverwrite -u myScratch
```

Now this error showed up :
*ERROR:  Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:AppMenu and file name:AppSwitcher.*

Thing is, push works and I haven't modified an App.
Also note that it worked on a older scratch with Summer release.

I'll take any idea or advice.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: This may be related to a version mismatch. Try the following command: `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release` then try your command again. To go back to the current version, use `salesforcedx@latest` instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried with pre-realease, latest or even an older version without success.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this SFDC Platform Winter19 bug

Create/update .forceignore file at the root of your SFDX Project, with the following content :

```
# List files or directories below to ignore them when running force:source:push, force:source:pull, and force:source:status
# More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm
#


AppSwitcher.appMenu
```

This doesn't solve the bug, but at least the sfdx force:source:pull doesn't crash

Comment: Thanks also!  I just hit this same problem and your .forceignore entry fixed it!

Comment: It's a known issue that's scheduled for release in Summer'19 -  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008e2HAAQ&title=unable-to-retrieve-appmenu-appswitcher

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Flows and this the following fixed it for me. Maybe it applies for the AppSwitcher problem as well:

I changed the Version from 43 to 44 in "sfdx-project.json" file in my local repository and tried to pull the changes again.

Source: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019fxEQAQ