# SFDX Can't Pull Source from Scratch Org "Metadata API received improper input" AppMenu and AppSwitcher

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I'm using SFDX and I made a change to the visibility of my app in my scratch org but when I try to pull the changes down (`sfdx force:source:pull`) I get:

> ERROR:  Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:AppMenu and file name:AppSwitcher.

Has anyone seen this error or know of a fix?

Comment: I ran into this the other day. The only thing that worked for me was adding `**.appmenu` to my `.forceignore` file.

Comment: Same problem and workaround here :) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/235290/33522

Comment: @JohnTowers are you a wizard? Haha, that was a great workaround. Much better than the one provided on the known issue. Thanks!